# WordPress get active users within a time period

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get a list of WordPress users within a time period who has published a post.
If the user has lets say not submitted a post within a month, then the user will be a non active user.

I have tried googling but found no solutions.

Comment: You can start building the funcionality researching this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwordpress%5D+users+active+answers%3A1..

Comment: Couldn't find anything related

Comment: Well, you're supposed to show what you've tried and what code you're having trouble with. Right now it's just "Please, research and write this code for me". I'm positive it's not your intention but it's just what's look like.... See [ask] and [tour].